# Выполнять некий скрипт по merge/accept

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Всем привет.**

Возник вопрос, а можно ли при merge accept из gitlab web автоматически обновлять содержимое папки на сервере?
Ну т.е. у меня исходник сайта живёт в gitlab, я и коллега иногда его правим средствами git и мёржим в мастер. После мёржа в мастер я иду на ssh и "актуализирую" сайт в www_root моего http сервера.
Вот хочется сделать это автоматически при megre в master. Вроде как есть скрипты. Но найти как и чего не могу. Может не там ищу?

Comment: Ключевое слово для гуглинга — Continuous Deployment / Continuous Delivery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать посредством [GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html)

- Устанавливаете сервис [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)
- В проекте конфигурируете [GitLab CI/CD Pipeline Configuration Reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html)